# PHP - Make nested if statement output shorter

Tags: php, if-statement

I often end up with something like below:

```
<?php
foreach($items as $item) {
  if($item['key']) {
    echo 'Alright';

    if($item['value']) {
      echo 'Inside';
    } else {
      $output[] = [
        $item['data1'],
        $item['data2'],
      ];
    }
  } else {
    $output[] = [
      $item['data1'],
      $item['data2'],
    ];
  }
}

print_r($output);
```

As you can see I use nested if statements. What nags me is that I have the same output in both `else`. I would prefer keep things DRY.

So, if I'm in an else statement anywhere within the foreach, I want to output the same results.

### Update

My real code is a bit more complex.

```
foreach($out as $i => $data) {
  $dayshort = mb_substr($data[0], 0, 3);

  if(isset($out[$i+1][0])) {
      $future = $out[$i+1][0];

      $daykey = array_search($data[0], $weekdays);
      $nextday = $weekdays[$daykey + 1];

      if($nextday != $future) {
          $backkey = array_search($future, $weekdays) - 1;
          $backname = mb_substr($weekdays[$backkey], 0, 3);

          $final[] = [
              $dayshort . ' - ' . $backname,
              $data[1],
              $data[2]
          ];
      } else {
          $final[] = [
              $data[0],
              $data[1],
              $data[2]
          ];
      }
  } else {
      $final[] = [
          $data[0],
          $data[1],
          $data[2]
      ];
  }
}
```

Now I've setup a repo here with the complete code: https://github.com/jenstornell/daybreaker

Comment: `if (!$item['key'] || !$item['value']) $output[] = ...; else ...`…?

Comment: Yes. I see now that my stripped down example did not do anything good. So I've posted another of my real code. Now that kind of solution will no longer work.

Comment: It still boils down to you simply having to structure your logic a bit differently so it falls through to `$output[] = ...` only once, and perhaps `continue`s the loop in other cases.

Comment: What problem does your code solve?

Comment: @Mast I've added the full repo link into the post: https://github.com/jenstornell/daybreaker You can probably see what it does.

Comment: Please include the problem description in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($out as $i => $data) {
  $dayshort = mb_substr($data[0], 0, 3);
  $result = $data[0]; /* default case value */

  if (isset($out[$i + 1][0])) {
     $future = $out[$i + 1][0];
     $daykey = array_search($data[0], $weekdays);
     $nextday = $weekdays[$daykey + 1];

     if ($nextday != $future) {
         $backkey = array_search($future, $weekdays) - 1;
         $backname = mb_substr($weekdays[$backkey], 0, 3);
         $result = $dayshort.' - '.$backname; /* overrite here */
     }
  }
 /* just once */
  $final[] = [
    $result,
    $data[1],
    $data[2]
  ];
}
```

Comment: Yes, for that example it would probably work. My foreach is more complex, so I've updated my post with my real code. Sorry about being misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more simpler

```
<?php
foreach($items as $item) {
  if($item['key']) {
    echo 'Alright';

    if($item['value'])
      echo 'Inside';
  }
  $output[] = [
    $item['data1'],
    $item['data2'],
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, for my stripped down example it would probably work. I see that I stripped it down too much. I've added an update with a real example.

Comment: Try this
`foreach($out as $i => $data) {
  $dayshort = mb_substr($data[0], 0, 3);

  $title = $data[0];
  if(isset($out[$i+1][0])) {
      $future = $out[$i+1][0];

      $daykey = array_search($data[0], $weekdays);
      $nextday = $weekdays[$daykey + 1];

      if($nextday != $future) {
          $backkey = array_search($future, $weekdays) - 1;
          $backname = mb_substr($weekdays[$backkey], 0, 3);

          $title = $dayshort . ' - ' . $backname;
      }
  }

  $final[] = [
      $title,
      $data[1],
      $data[2]
  ];
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a variable for else part like

$is_false=0;

Set it to "1" once you are in else block and at last step check this variable and if it is "1" set the outout or else block code.

Refer the code below.

```
<?php
foreach($items as $item) {
    if($item['key']) {
        echo 'Alright';
        if($item['value']) {
            echo 'Inside';
        } else {
            $is_false = 1;
        }
    }else{
        $is_false = 1;
    }

    if($is_false==1){
        $output[] = [
        $item['data1'],
        $item['data2'],
        ];
    }
}    
print_r($output);
```